# Ajax not working in JQuery form plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am implementing Jquery form plugin with ajax for insertion my form in db. Validation working fine but ajax call not receiving any data in response.
Perhaps, i don't know the exact way to do it.
Help me by guiding the true way to use this plugin.
Thanks.

JS_File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup_form').formValidation({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
             // Here i have defined some rules
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

 var firstName =   $('.name').val();
 var email =   $('.email').val();
 var password =   $('.password').val();

            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(e.target);
            $form.ajaxSubmit({
                // You can change the url option to desired target
                url: $form.attr('form_process.php'),
                type: 'POST',
                 data:{'FirstName':firstName,'Email':email,'Password':password},

                success: function(responseText) {
                        alert(responseText);
                }
            });

        });
});
```

form_process.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['FirstName']) && isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Password'])
        && isset($_POST['City']) && isset($_POST['Country']))
{
            echo $firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
           echo $em = $_POST['Email'];
           echo $ftName = $_POST['Password'];
           echo $ame = $_POST['City'];
           echo $firame = $_POST['Country'];
}
```

Comment: echo json_encode( array("type"=>"success","data"=>$data_array) );
die;
pass data in json format.

Comment: You are not sending the `City` nor the `Country` so you will never enter the `if` statement so unless you have output after that, you will not see anything...

Comment: @RohanVeer
Did not work

Comment: @RohanVeer
What is the value of $data_array?

Comment: @TheFlash
 According to you, when i tried to write url: $form.attr('action'), and specified action in <form> ,i am recieving a blank page in response

Comment: @TheFlash
It's displaying all values sending from ajax request on a new page.
But why, i am redirecting to a new page, i used ajax to prevent this behavior. I want to receive all these values as an alert on the same page and tha's what i am not receiving.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide you need to subscribe to form's submit event and prevent forms default action

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide see my edit

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide You can pass your values like this - 
echo json_encode( array("type"=>"success","firstname"=>$firstname,"em"=>$em) ); 
die;

Comment: @RohanVeer
Like what ?

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide see additional fix 2

Comment: @fsacer
I already implemented  additional fixes but still getting no response

Comment: @fsacer
After implementing additional fixes, my page has stopped to going to the next page, now it';s not showing any response from server side script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing City and Country from ajax, but still you are trying to get value of those fields, and even you also put condition in php that if  FirstName, Email, Password, City, Country all are set then only go in if condition.

So 2 solution available:

1) Remove City and Country from id condition and dot try to get it

```
if(isset($_POST['FirstName']) && isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Password']))
{
           echo $firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
           echo $em = $_POST['Email'];
           echo $ftName = $_POST['Password'];          
}
```

2) Pass City and Country from ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup_form').formValidation({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
             // Here i have defined some rules
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

 var firstName =   $('.name').val();
 var email =   $('.email').val();
 var password =   $('.password').val();
 var city = $(".city").val();
 var state = $(".state").val(); 

            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(e.target);
            $form.ajaxSubmit({
                // You can change the url option to desired target
                url: $form.attr('form_process.php'),
                type: 'POST',
                 data:{'FirstName':firstName,'Email':email,'Password':password,'City':city,'State':state},

                success: function(responseText) {
                        alert(responseText);
                }
            });

        });
});
```

Comment: I removed city and country from both files but still i am not getting any response in alert after form submission

Comment: do you see any error in ajax request in console? 404 or 500 ??

Comment: in that case just check if it is going into if condition or not in php file?

Comment: I am getting not any response, even after writing else condition

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error is here where you are setting the `url`:

```
url: $form.attr('form_process.php'),
```

You are saying that the form has attribute `form_process.php` which contains the url. You probably meant this:

```
url: $form.attr('action'),
```

**Additional fixes:**

- Subscribe to forms submit event and prevent default action:

> $('#signup_form').submit(function(e){
>          e.preventDefault();
>       });

- Try to set ajaxSubmit before submit happens - means moving code up from the event `success.form.bv`:

  ```
      $('#signup_form').ajaxSubmit({
              // You can change the url option to desired target
              url: $form.attr('form_process.php'),
              type: 'POST',
               data:{'FirstName':firstName,'Email':email,'Password':password},

              success: function(responseText) {
                      alert(responseText);
              }
          });
  ```
- You might be using the plugin the wrong way make the form first working without ajax and then do the AJAX using the follownig examples http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm from plugins site.

Comment: @TheFlash nope sorry

Comment: @fsacer
According to TheFlash and you, when i tried to write url: $form.attr('action'), and specified action in <form> ,i am recieving a blank page in response

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide you need to subscribe to form's submit event and prevent forms default action

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide $('#signup_form').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault;});

Comment: @fsacer
What does it mean ?
"you need to subscribe to form's submit event and prevent forms default action"

Comment: @fsacer
My if condition do not working in form_process.php

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Forms default is to post/get data from url specified in action -> this means it will go to another page. But because you want to stay on the same page you need to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Server side code will work because AJAX will do the post request for you.

Comment: @fsacer
I see your edited post and modifies my code but my if condition is not working and still it is redirecting to the next page

Comment: @fsacer
I don't know why my server side script not working and it's saying  error as specified in else part .

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide might be using this plugin the wrong way http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm, it's meant to just add the functionality of ajax to standard implemented form. Please look at he examples

Comment: @fsacer
You meant to say that i should stop to use this plugin more ?

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide No i meant that you should make a working site without it, and then just add it in.

Comment: @fsacer
I have 10 fields in my form in which i am just trying to pass 3-4 fields value in ajax. Is it possible that the problem is there because of this fact ???

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide this might be one of the problems yes. Maybe you should use id's and name both same - to name the input fields and then see if they show up after you post hem to php site.